# Using JQuery to get text of a div that's a child of a header to replace a different header

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, target, children

I'm trying to get the text contents of a .div('.child#') child of my event.target('h6.class'), and replace my other headers('h1.replacHeader#') using this script below...

```
$('h6.HeaderToBeClicked').click(function(event) { 
    var $target = $(this);
    $('.replaceHeader1').replaceWith("<h1 class='replaceHeader1'>" + $target.children(".child1").text() + "</h1>");
    $('.replaceHeader2').replaceWith("<h1 class='replaceHeader2'>" + $target.children(".child2").text() + "</h1>");
    });

});

HTML:
<div id="ReplaceTheseHeaders">
    <h1 class='replaceHeader1'></h1>
    <h1 class='replaceHeader2'></h1>
</div>
<div id="accordian" class="acc">
    <?php $counter = 1; ?>
    <?php foreach ($tmpl->vars as $var) { ?>
    <h6 class="HeaderToBeClicked"><a href="#">
    <div class="counter"><?php print $counter . "." ?></div>
        <div class="child1"><?php print $var['title'];?></div>
    <div class="child2"><?php print $var['name'];?></div>
    </a></h6>
<?php $counter = $counter+1; ?>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

I've noticed that .text() apparently doesn't apply to an event.target... So how could I go about achieving this?

Comment: When the h6.class is clicked, the .replaceHeaders headers will change to that of the div.class#  which is a child of the clicked h6.class

Comment: To better explain, I have 2 dynamic divs inside my header class, when the entire header is clicked the divs inside the clicked header should replace the headers elsewhere on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$target` is intended to refer to the `h6.class` element, then you should change this line:

```
var $target = $(event.target);
```

to this:

```
var $target = $(this);
```

`$(event.target)` will actually refer to whatever descendant element was clicked. The event then bubbles up to the element that has the handler (`h6.class`) which is referenced with `$(this)`.

---

**EDIT:**

If this is similar to your HTML, the code runs perfectly. If (for example) `.child1` and `.child2` are nested deeper inside `h6.class`, then we would need to change things up a bit.

```
<h6 class='class'>
    <div class='child1'>this is child 1</div>
    <div class='child2'>this is child 2</div>
</h6>

<div class="replaceHeader1">header1</div>
<div class="replaceHeader2">header2</div>
<div class="replaceHeader1">header1</div>
<div class="replaceHeader2">header2</div>
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

Given the HTML you posted, try the code below. Please note that you don't seem to have a closing tag for your `<a href="#">` element. The code below should work either way though.

```
$('h6.HeaderToBeClicked').click(function(event) { 
    var $target = $(this);
    $('.replaceHeader1').text( $target.find(".child1").text() );
    $('.replaceHeader2').text( $target.find(".child2").text() );
});
```

This assumes you're just change the content of your `.replaceHeader` elements. If you need to change the tag name as well, you'll need to go back to using `replaceWith()`.

Comment: Thank you I'm not too well versed in JS but that seemed to help a bit, now I'm getting [object Object] instead of an emptyset.... but now how do I get the text from the div i'm using to replace the header text?

Comment: well actually was getting back both empty and 'undefined'

Comment: You should probably post a sample of your HTML in your question. Otherwise it is just impossible to tell if you're using the correct selectors and traversal functions.

Comment: If you're just replacing the content of the `replaceHeader` elements, you don't need `replaceWith()`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, yeah the a tag was left in there on accident, I had cleaned up my code before I posted it to make it more universal and understandable.  Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. If you don't have the `<a>` tag, then you can use `.children(...)` like you had. But, `.find()` will work either way.